# How to connect to mariadb5.5.52 using python3

Tags: python, django, mariadb

My development environment

python3.8
mariadb 5.5.52
pymysql 1.0.2
django 4.1.3

try to migrate
but vscode tips django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MariaDB 10.3 or later is required (found 5.5.52).

Comment: You can move to a very old unsupported django that does support MariaDB-5.5.52, or you could update your MariaDB to 10.3 or later and enjoy its newer features as well as the current django features.

Comment: https://mariadb.org/mariadb-55-rip/